# Help with capacitor circuit calculations

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Hopefully somebody will be able to help me better understand how to calculate capacitor change and everything else. I just started studying them. The problem and my attempt to solve it is below.

How would I go about to get E (energy) and Q for each capacitor? thanks!!!

**EDITED AFTER COMMENTS**

**GIVEN:**

C1 = 20 uF

C4 =  2 uF

C6 = 70 uF

C8 = 10 uF

V(total)  = 3 kV

**Find** V voltage, E energy, Q electrical charge for each capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvRSM4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First I simplify the circuit and calculate C46:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZgwqN.png)</sup>

$$ C_{46}=C4 + C6 = 2uF + 70uF = 72uF $$

$$ C_{total} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{C1}}+\frac{1}{\text{C8}}+\frac{1}{\text{C46}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{20}}+\frac{1}{\text{10}}+\frac{1}{\text{72}}}=6.1017 uF=6.1017*10^{-6} F $$

---

$$ Q = Q1 = Q8 = Q46 = 6.1017*10^{-6}*3000 = 1.83051*10^{-2} C $$

---

$$ V1 = \frac{\text{Q1}}{\text{C1}} = \frac{1.83051*10^{-2}}{2*10^{-5}} = 9.15255*10^{2} V $$

$$ V8 = \frac{\text{Q8}}{\text{C8}} = \frac{1.83051*10^{-2}}{1*10^{-5}} = 1.83051 * 10^{3} V $$

$$ V46 = \frac{\text{Q46}}{\text{C46}} = \frac{1.83051*10^{-2}}{7.2*10^{-5}} = 2.5424 * 10^{2} V $$

---

$$ E = \frac{\text{V*Q}}{\text{2}} = \frac{3000*1.83051*10^{-2}}{2} = 2.7458*10^{-2} J $$

$$ E1 = \frac{\text{V1*Q1}}{\text{2}} = \frac{9.15255*10^{2}*1.83051*10^{-2}}{2} = 8.3769 J $$

$$ E46 = \frac{\text{V46*Q46}}{\text{2}} = \frac{2.5424*10^{2}*1.83051*10^{-2}}{2} = 2.3269 J $$

$$ E8 = \frac{\text{V8*Q8}}{\text{2}} = \frac{1.83051*10^{3}*1.83051*10^{-2}}{2} = 1.6754 *10^{1} J $$

---

$$Q4 = C4*V4 = 2*10^{-6} * 2.3225*10^{3} = 4.6450*10^{-3} V$$
$$Q6 = C6*V6 = 7*10^{-5} * 2.3225*10^{3} = 1.6258*10^{-1} V$$

$$E4 = \frac{\text{V4*Q4}}{\text{2}} = \frac{2.3225*10^{3}*4.6450*10^{3}}{2} = 5.3940*10^{6} J $$

$$E6 = \frac{\text{V6*Q6}}{\text{2}} = \frac{2.3225*10^{3}*1.6258*10^{5}}{2} = 1.88796*10^{8} J $$

Comment: Check your math/thoughts for C46....

Comment: This can't be solved without knowing the history of the circuit. Were all capacitors initially fully discharged and then the power source was connected?

Comment: @Trevor Whats the problem with C46? C4 and C6 are in series, combining two of them in series thats the formula, isn't it?

Comment: "C4 and C6 are in series"............ Are they?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think you are over thinking the circuit. It is a simplest circuit that we were given on the first day in school. I am just not understanding.

Comment: @Trevor indeed, I can move it down and draw in parallel. Thats true, I didn't see that :) So I should calculate it in parallel and go from there... :) Thanks

Comment: @Trevor could you please take a look again? I did a few changes to calculations and circuit. Am I on a correct path? Whats next?

Comment: There is a substitution error when you calculate V46. Instead of putting 72uF you are putting Ctotal on C46.

Comment: Yup what @next-hack said...

Comment: We can only assume \$ Q=Q1=Q8=Q46 \$ if all capacitors are perfect (no leakage) and they all started with the same charge: For example they all started fully discharged and so each had a charge of 0 coulombs. Otherwise this can't be solved.

Comment: Watch your powers on V8 .. answer ought to be 1,830.508V

Comment: Once you have the voltages calculating the energies should be a snap..

Comment: @Trevor I've added more calculations. Again... am I on a right path?

Comment: Your process is right but you have made some errors. Here is a tip. Check your math using the other E equation \$E=CV^2/2\$

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll take a break now and continue in a few hours :)

Comment: @Trevor could you add an answer to this post. I'd like to accept it as you help me the most. Thanks!

Comment: @gointern just accept Warren's answer. He has the basics in a nut shell without doing it step by step. Glad you got there in the end, other than the one misread of the schematic, and a few execution errors, you did fine on your own too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider two capacitors in series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1K12E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then we know \$ V_{C1} + V_{C2} = V_{tot} \$ but we have no way of determining how this is shared because lets say \$ C1 = C2 = 1 \mu F\$ and \$ V_{tot} = 300 \text{V} \$ for example then there is nothing to say the voltage has to be shared equally because one capacitor may have had some initial charge which makes this claim invalid.  Also since no current is flowing at DC the voltages across the capacitors will be dominated by the leakage resistance of the capacitors and not the capacitor values.

If we are assuming a purely theoretical answer then we can ignore leakage resistance and if we assume all capacitors were initially fully discharged we can assume that \$ Q_{C1} = Q_{C2} \$ since \$ Q = \int i \text{ dt} \$ and since all capacitors initially had zero charge and have had identical current flowing in them at all times since.

---

With that caveat in place the approach to this type of this problem is:

1. Calculate total capacitance (you have done this already).
2. Calculate total charge \$ Q = C{tot} \cdot V{tot} \$.
3. Calculate the charge in each series element,  they all have the same \$ Q = Q_{C1} = Q_{C2} \$.
4. Calculate the voltage across each capacitor \$  Q = C \cdot V \Rightarrow V = \frac{Q}{C} \$
5. Calculate the energy in each capacitor \$ E = \frac{1}{2} \cdot C \cdot V^2 \$

Comment: Sorry @Trevor you are correct, edited

Comment: :) No worries.. it always gets me too. The truth seems counter-intuitive.